# Dart pub update failed

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart-editor

I am getting the following error when trying to do a pub update to get the `web_ui` package installed.

**Dart Editor version :** 0.2.10_r16761

**Dart SDK version :** 0.2.10.1_r16761

The `"Help > About > Check for Update..."` also gives me `"Unable to get latest revision"`.  Is it a proxy problem maybe?

Is there a manual way to add packages, e.g. download the package and put it somewhere?

```
Running pub update ...
Pub update failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...
Got socket error trying to find package "web_ui" at http://pub.dartlang.org.
OS Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
, errno = 10060
```

Comment: Are you behind an http proxy server?  pub does not support proxies:  http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5454 and http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5455

Comment: try `ping pub.dartlang.org` to debug your network connection. what does it say?

Comment: @Kyrra I am indeed behind a proxy and as Seth mentioned in the issues you listed, this is the case in most large organization so there is a clear need for a better solution.  I would like to add that changing environment variables is also not a good solution since most employees don't have admin rights and are unable to make these changes.

Comment: @Seth "Request Timed Out"

Comment: We know we need to add proxy support, sorry for the troubles and we appreciate you starring the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment discussion, this issue is due to you being behind a HTTP Proxy server.  The Dart Editor and Dart Pub do no honor a system's proxy settings and only work if you have a normal connection out to the web.  There are currently 2 bugs written up that the Dart team will hopefully fix at some point, but they are not there yet.

Please see more details about this issue on the bugs and star the bugs if you would like it to be fixed.

- Bug 5455: [Allow Dart Editor to use a proxy for updates](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5455)
- Bug 5454: [Allow Pub to use an HTTP Proxy](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5454)